# Extjs combobox in not loading the data in Internet explorer

Tags: extjs3

the following store is working in google chrome and firefox, it is not working with IE 8

```
  var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
 fields: ['productname'],
 url: 'productnames.jsp',

autoLoad: true });new Ext.form.ComboBox({
            fieldLabel: 'Product Name',
            hideTrigger: true, 
            name: 'productname',
            id:'productname',
            mode: 'local',
            store: store,
            displayField: 'productname',
            triggerAction: 'all',
            emptyText:'Select Product',
            allowBlank:     false,
            editable:       false,
            forceSelection: true,

            listeners:{select:{fn:function() {
            var selectvalue=this.getValue();
            store1.load({   params: {productname: selectvalue} });

            } }},
            anchor:'95%'
           })
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, everything looks like it should be working fine.  I would take a look at your JSON that is returned.  There might be an extra "," at the end of it or something.  Normally Internet Explorer has the biggest issues with extra commas at the end of scripts/returns/etc. and Firefox and Chrome do not.  But with the above code, it looks like everything should be working fine.